# Jquery Isolation

Tags: jquery

My company has a web application that has a plain javascript in it, and it use $ -"dollar symbol" in it's own way as shown:

```
function $(e) {
    return document.getElementById(e);
}
```

The problem is when I embed the jquery to the page there is a conflict occurs.
Is there a way that I can isolate the jquery example:

$$(this) - is to call jquery
and
$(this) - to call old staff

please help me thank you

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure you include your lib first, then call

```
$.noConflict();
var $$ = jQuery;
```

That will restore `$` to what it used to be before jQuery was parsed and make `$$` point to `jQuery` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Thanks buddy, ya all made my day. By the way I hope there are no bottleneck for this.

Comment: @INgeeg What do you mean bottlenecks? Performance is the exact same when accessing it through `$$`. Calling `$.noConflict()` itself does not take time at all.