# jQuery Master-Detail select list not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to isolate [this jsfiddle script](http://jsfiddle.net/kzv8x573/) but for some reason I cannot see, isolation is not working and firebug does not report anything to the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#sel2").prop("disabled", true);

        $( "#sel1" ).change(function() {
          var value = $(this).val();
            $("#sel2").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#sel2 > option").hide();
            $("#sel2 > option[value*='" + value +"']").show();
        });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="mobile-phone" class="mobile-phone" id='sel1'>
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
                <option value="Samsung">Samsung</option>
                <option value="HTC">HTC</option>
                <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
            </select>
            <select name="mobile-model" class="mobile-model" id='sel2'>
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="Nokia--Lumia-520">Lumia 520</option>
                <option value="Nokia--Lumia-620">Lumia 620</option>
                <option value="Samsung--Galaxy-s3">Galaxy S3</option>
                <option value="Samsung--Galaxy-s4">Galaxy S4</option>
                <option value="HTC--hero">Hero</option>
                <option value="HTC--one">One</option>
                <option value="Apple--iphone4">iPhone 4</option>
                <option value="Apple--iphone5">iPhone 5</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: see answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717764/jquery-isolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap a document ready function

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("#sel2").prop("disabled", true);

    $( "#sel1" ).change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value !="Select")
        {
            $("#sel2").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#sel2 > option").hide();
            $("#sel2 > option:eq(0)").prop('selected', true);
            $("#sel2 > option[value*='" + value +"']").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#sel2").prop("disabled", true)
        }
    });
    });
```